# Fix Quick Look for TypeScript files

Tags: macos, typescript

My Mac recognises the .ts extension as MPEG-2 Transport Stream, while I use it more often as TypeScript files. Because of that Quick Look does not show the contents of .ts files.

I found on Stackoverflow that I should be able to assign custom extensions to the text editor, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Right click the file -> Open with ... -> choose Application -> Choose your text editor -> check "Always use this app". (From the top of my head, actual text might differ)

Comment: That only changes associations that open the file not the extension type itself. It still does not make the quickly work (I have ql-colorcode installed).

Answer (score 17):

[QLColorCode](https://github.com/anthonygelibert/QLColorCode) is a very nice Quick Look plugin which allows you to set syntax highlighting for **ANY** extension file you want.

**1. Install QLColorCode Quick Look plugin**

If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), you can install it with:

```sh
brew cask install qlcolorcode
```

Otherwise, you can just copy / paste the `QLColorCode.qlgenerator` to your `~/Library/QuickLook/` folder from a [release](https://github.com/anthonygelibert/QLColorCode/releases).

**2. Add .ts and .tsx syntax highlighting support**

- First get the *kMDItemContentType* of the extension you want to quick look at with the plugin:

```sh
mdls -name kMDItemContentType /path/to/any/file.ts
```

- Add an entry with the string returned by the previous command to the plugin settings list — for a `.ts` file, this should be `public.mpeg-2-transport-stream`. To do so, just open the file `~/Library/QuickLook/QLColorCode.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist` with any text editor (it's not a compiled file) and in the section `CFBundleDocumentTypes > Item 0 > LSItemContentTypes` (~ 15th line), add a line like this:

```xml
<string>public.mpeg-2-transport-stream</string>
```

You can find more information on how to add language type support to the plugin in the project [README.md](https://github.com/anthonygelibert/QLColorCode#adding-language-types).

---

Here is the [original post](https://gregbrown.co/code/typescript-quicklook) where I found all this useful information.

Comment: macOS Catalina, I can't find the CFBundleDocumentTypes node in the plist.

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a way to make QuickLook to preview any file extension as text? Like a catch all. QLStephen only works for files without any extension

Comment: As of MacOS Big Sur the command is `brew install --cask qlcolorcode`

Answer (score 5):

According this [article](http://amitp.blogspot.cz/2014/06/mac-os-index-source-code.html), there is another solution:

**1) Remove filetype definition** from: `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Info.plist`
You need to do that in recovery mode.

```
215 => {
      "UTTypeConformsTo" => "public.movie"
      "UTTypeDescription" => "MPEG-2 Transport Stream"
      "UTTypeIdentifier" => "public.mpeg-2-transport-stream"
      "UTTypeTagSpecification" => {
        "public.filename-extension" => [
          0 => "ts"
        ]
      }
    }
```

**2) Then run**
`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill`

Comment: Thank you. It works for me. Few think worth to mention though. First, I had to open this file by using xcode.app, otherwise encoding wasn't recognized by any of my editors. Second, I had to add write permission to myself for Info.plist file as well as to folder containing it. And third - it was enough for me to just remove "ts" value from "public.filename-extension" array, no need to remove entire record.

Comment: @Ihor Did you edit the file in recovery mode? How did you start XCode.app in recovery mode?

Comment: @jbandi, no. I've edited this file during normal Mac OS run. But to be possible to edit this file - make sure you have correct permissions. See my previous comment. Or if you have any other issue - please explain in more details.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get QuickLook to display .ts files as plain text.

The necessary step was to remove `Movie.qlgenerator` from the directory `/System/Library/QuickLook`.

The downside is, that QuickLook can't preview any types of movies any more...

**Update 2016-04-12:**
In OSX El Capitan it seems not possible to simply remove a file from `/System/Library/QuickLook` (probably because of [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection)).

I managed to remove the `Movie.qlgenerator` with the following steps:

1. Back up the file first
2. Boot into Recovery Mode: Restart and press-and-hold Cmd-R
3. Open a terminal
4. disable SIP: `csrutil disable`
5. `cd /Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/Library/QuickLook` (your volume name may be different)
6. `rm -rf Movie.qlgenerator`
7. `csrutil enable`
8. `csrutil status` -> Verify SIP is turned on again
9. Restart

After the above steps I could quick-look my `.ts` files.

The best part: I put the `Movie.qlgenerator` I had backed up in the first step into `~/Library/QuickLook` and now I have also quick-look previews for movies ...

Comment: How did you remove `Movie.qlgenerator` (Trying with `sudo rm -R` doesn't make it)

Comment: @Manu: See my update in the answer for OSX El Capitan